# Double the review limit once the gold badge for the queue has been obtained

Tags: discussion, review, flags, badges, vote-to-close

I think users who have earned the gold badge in a queue should be allowed to review twice as many posts.

Right now, I see

> Thank you for reviewing 20 low quality posts today; come back in 7 hours to continue reviewing.

and

> Thank you for reviewing 40 close votes today; come back in 7 hours to continue reviewing.

on Stack Overflow. I have the gold badge in each of these queues, and I'm willing to do more reviews. I think users with the gold badge should be allowed to do twice as many reviews.

I agree with [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243337/202832), which points out that

> If you have earned a gold badge for a queue, you can get more reviews in it. Because if you review after you got it, you review for the quality of the site, not for badges.

Comment: I think _everyone_ should have higher limits on the reviews, then everyone is happy.

Comment: @Unihedron Robo-reviewers are a huge issue. If you got higher review limits from day 1, when you're trying to earn the badges, you're more likely to robo-review.

Comment: I don't think reputation is a good metric for deciding who to give more revs to.

Comment: I think this should be based on relevant stats. Since review tasks taken isn't a viable scale, we could work with net helpful flag stats, much like the maximum flag per day system is in place.

Comment: Passing 50 audits in a row or something.

Comment: @bjb568 Absolutely not. The audit system is rather fallible.

Comment: Well, what else is there? Flags aren't really related. Number of anything will increase robos…

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262436/should-the-review-limit-be-determined-by-the-users-pass-fail-audit-ratio

Answer (score 3):

*Note: this answer doesn't repeat what the question said, because it was posted when [another revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/243334/1) was present.*

I agree with what bjb568 says:

> I don't think reputation is a good metric for deciding who to give more revs to.

You said that most 10k users have the gold badges. Any stats for that? And even if most 10k users have them, there certainly are 10k users around who don't have them and if they get more reviews, they might start robo-reviewing.

What might be better? If you have earned a gold badge for a queue, you can get more reviews in it. Because if you review after you got it, you review for the quality of the site, not for badges.